# Multiple consumers on one RabbitMQ queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm following this guide from RabbitMQ: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html. I want to emulate this functionality with multiple threads on one queue.

If I start my Receivers before I start the Sender, it works as expected, shown below:

```
[*] Rcvr1 Waiting for messages...
[*] Rcvr2 Waiting for messages...
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 0'
[x] Rcvr2 Received 'Hello 1'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 2'
[x] Rcvr2 Received 'Hello 3'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 4'
[x] Rcvr2 Received 'Hello 5'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 6'
[x] Rcvr2 Received 'Hello 7'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 8'
...
```

However, starting my Receivers first causes only one thread to receive messages(The last thread to be started):

```
[*] Rcvr2 Waiting for messages...
[*] Rcvr1 Waiting for messages...
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 9'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 10'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 11'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 12'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 13'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 14'
[x] Rcvr1 Received 'Hello 15'
...
```

Interestingly enough, if I start the sender, then start receiver, as above, then start the sender again(while receiver is process the first batch). The first messages sent are processed serially while the second batch are processed in parallel, or at least with the remaining threads.:

```
 [*] Rcvr1 Waiting for messages...
 [*] Rcvr2 Waiting for messages...
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 0'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 1'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 2'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 3'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 4'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 5'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 6'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 7'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 8'
 [x] Rcvr2 Received '[Batch 2] Hello 1'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 9'
 [x] Rcvr2 Received '[Batch 2] Hello 3'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 10'
 [x] Rcvr2 Received '[Batch 2] Hello 5'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 11'
 [x] Rcvr2 Received '[Batch 2] Hello 7'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 12'
 [x] Rcvr2 Received '[Batch 2] Hello 9'
 [x] Rcvr1 Received '[Batch 1] Hello 13'
 [x] Rcvr2 Received '[Batch 2] Hello 11'
```

This is clearly possible with RabbitMQ, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My simple code is as follows:

Sender

```
public class Send {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
             Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
            for(int x=0; x<100; x++) {
                String message = "Hello "+x;
                channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver

```
package com.mawv.ingest.rabbitmq;

import com.rabbitmq.client.*;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Recv {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ThreadPoolExecutor rcvrPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");

        Runnable rcvr1 = () -> {
            try {
                Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
                Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
                channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);

                System.out.println(" [*] Rcvr1 Waiting for messages...");
                DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
                    Envelope envelope = delivery.getEnvelope();
                    String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println(" [x] Rcvr1 Received '" + message + "'");
                    long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
                    channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, true);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception ex) { }

                };
                channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {  });

            } catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        Runnable rcvr2 = () -> {
            try {
                Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
                Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
                channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);

                System.out.println(" [*] Rcvr2 Waiting for messages...");
                DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
                    Envelope envelope = delivery.getEnvelope();
                    String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println(" [x] Rcvr2 Received '" + message + "'");
                    long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
                    channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, true);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                };
                channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {
                });
            } catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        rcvrPool.execute(rcvr1);
        rcvrPool.execute(rcvr2);

    }
}
```

I've also tied this example, exactly as they describe it and see the same results. https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2015/09/rabbitmq-one-producer-and-multiple.html

I'm assuming somethings not right with my setup.

Answer (score 1):

According to RabbitMQ api:

"While a Channel can be used by multiple threads, it's important to ensure that only one thread executes a command at once. Concurrent execution of commands will likely cause an UnexpectedFrameError to be thrown"

First of all I think you should use different channels for different threads.

Finally I think the first thread is terminated because it's idle, so only the second one is active and does the whole work. One thread is enough in this situation.

Take a look at the ThreadPoolExecutor api for java 8:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

For instance you can find:

"By default, even core threads are initially created and started only when new tasks arrive, but this can be overridden dynamically using method prestartCoreThread() or prestartAllCoreThreads(). You probably want to prestart threads if you construct the pool with a non-empty queue"

and

"If the pool currently has more than corePoolSize threads, excess threads will be terminated if they have been idle for more than the keepAliveTime (see getKeepAliveTime(TimeUnit))."

You should use prestartAllCoreThreads() or prestartCoreThreads() to get the core threads up even when idle or getKeepAliveTime(TimeUnit) to keep them alive even if idle.

Comment: HI Saxon, please see revised code. I've tried new channels and even new connections & channels. I even tried creating two instances of the application(single threaded) with the exact same results. The receiver started first gets all the messages while the second receiver gets none.

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry! I didn't see the code very well.

Comment: Which java client version are you using?

Comment: I'm using client version 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was missing a critical channel config. This solved my issue:

channel.basicQos(1);

This what RabbitMQ has to say about it.

> Fair dispatch
>
> You might have noticed that the dispatching still doesn't work exactly
> as we want. For example in a situation with two workers, when all odd
> messages are heavy and even messages are light, one worker will be
> constantly busy and the other one will do hardly any work. Well,
> RabbitMQ doesn't know anything about that and will still dispatch
> messages evenly.
>
> This happens because RabbitMQ just dispatches a message when the
> message enters the queue. It doesn't look at the number of
> unacknowledged messages for a consumer. It just blindly dispatches
> every n-th message to the n-th consumer.
>
> In order to defeat that we can use the basicQos method with the
> prefetchCount = 1 setting. This tells RabbitMQ not to give more than
> one message to a worker at a time. Or, in other words, don't dispatch
> a new message to a worker until it has processed and acknowledged the
> previous one. Instead, it will dispatch it to the next worker that is
> not still busy.